# CakePHP multiple "has many" links

Tags: cakephp

am running CakePHP 2.4.6 and have two tables/models with multiple foreign key relationships. In simplified terms, I have an StockGroup model which is linked to an Account model by two foreign keys - sale_account_id and purchase_account_id. The documentation tells me to set up a $hasMany structure in the Account model like this :

```
public $hasMany = array(
    "StockGroupSaleAccount" => array(
        "className" => "StockGroup",
        "foreignKey" => "sale_account_id"
    ),
    "StockGroupPurchaseAccount" => array(
        "className" => "StockGroup",
        "foreignKey" => "purchase_account_id"
    )
);
```

When I try to open a view, I get the message

"Error: StockGroupSaleAccounts controller not found" (if I use the alias "StockGroup", the same as the class name then there is no problem, but that stops me specifying the multiple links).

Comment: It seems you have a little confusin between models and controllers. You are creating relationships between models, this does not create new controllers. Why are you trying to access "StockGroupSaleAccountsController" at all? Try to explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thankyou. The point is exactly that I do NOT want to create another controller - I just want to include the multiple foreign keys in the model. As far as I can see, I am following the specified procedure for this. The message just comes up in all of the Account views if I use a "hasMany" alias that is different from the class name.

Comment: what url are you visiting? Consider posting your whole error stack and part of your code where the error is generated

Comment: Thanks again, arilia. "Posting the error stack" sounds a bit technical for me, but it has nudged me into taking a second look at the woffle that is displayed on screen, and it mentioned the "beforeRender" function, which seems to be where the problem is. Reference to the $model property seems to be causing the trouble, so I will look at that. I have not had occasion to need a "hasMany" alias before, so that is probably why I have come across this problem for the first time. Thanks again.

Comment: I mean enable debug mode (if you don't know how take a look at the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#cakephp-core-configuration) and copy/paste or post a screenshot of what you see at screen. You wrote that you see a 'controller not found error', this ususally means that you are accessing a wrong url

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean now - once I had guessed what the problem was, it was easy do demonstrate it with a debug call. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

False alarm, I'm afraid! Was extracting data belonging to the linked tables, and was using the keys from $hasMany to get the model, and thence the relevant controller name - which was obviously incorrect in this situation - have now corrected it to look at the class name. Thanks for your help and forbearance!